# UIButton move animated problem

Tags: iphone

how to make a UIButton when moving (animated) without shadow? i tried the code but cannot make it can someone modifify or point out the problem

```
-(IBAction)move{

point=CGPointMake(0,1);
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    NSLog(@"fdfafa");



    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setType:@"push"];
    [animation setSubtype:@"fromBottom"];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    //[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

    [testButton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];

    testButton.center = CGPointMake(testButton.center.x, testButton.center.y + point.y);

   }
NSLog(@"%f",testButton.center.y);

}
```

or have other better method to make a object move animated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
button.center = CGPointMake(x,y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: this is for UIView but not UIButton,how about UIButton

Comment: Thos are class methods to UIView :)